# I need Subsequence of a particular length, in Groovy

Tags: groovy, sequence

I have a Groovy code like this to find the `subsequence` :

```
def number = "248" as List
def number1= number.subsequences()
```

Which outputs :

```
[[8], [2, 4, 8], [2, 8], [2], [4, 8], [4], [2, 4]]
```

Now what I want is a subsequence of a particular length. Lets say for example I want only the subsequence of length 3, then for our example we need to get only `[2, 4, 8]` as output.

How to do this in groovy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use findAll:

```
    number.subsequences().findAll { it.size() == 3 }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer :D after a long time I'm seeing you on SO :D